# please help solve v02 formula

Tags: probability-theory

How can I simplify the formula:

$[\{x/15 \times 1.33\} \times 0.17] + 33.3$, where $x$ is traveled distance

I don't know what the "$[$" and the "$\{$" are for.

Can anyone please explain?

Note: this is Staminanya stability formula for running.

Comment: These are simple brackets. It's the same as using "(".

Comment: And you can remove them confidently

Comment: now i get it, thanks to both of you, and @goodvibration too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square "[" and curly "{" brackets in this case are both uses as parentheses. Evaluate $[\{x/15 \times 1.33\} \times 0.17] + 33.3$ the same as you would $((x/15 \times 1.33) \times 0.17) + 33.3$.

After simplifying, you can get, $0.0150733\times x + 33.3$.

Does this help?